# Double Animation Using Path in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I cant find DoubleAnimationUsingPath in any of the reference paths. For example the furthest I can get is System.Windows.Media.Animation - but I dont see DoubleAnimationUsingPath inside it! I am trying to make a web project where I want to move objects (rectangles) to produce a certain animation.

I am using Silverlight5 and .NET4.0 , the IDE is Visual Studio 2010.  Dont know what I am missing.

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now Silverlight doesn't support DoubleAnimationUsingPath. But its available in WPF. That's why you are not able to find it in Silverlight.

But you have another option open. Checkout this example/Sample Code: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/PathAnimation.aspx?display=Print